# Travelpayouts API signature create with city ID

Tags: php, api

I am facing a problem. I have used Travelpayouts hotels API in my site. First send a request with signature for getting search ID and then sent a request with signature for getting API  information. I can sent the request. All above the think I can do by IATA code. But I want to search with specific Country/county/city/hotel. How can I do that? I have read [Hotel search API](https://support.travelpayouts.com/hc/en-us/articles/203956133-Hotel-search-API). There are showing only search example of with IATA code and I have saw this note in the request parameters of 'Hotel search API' documentation **"Note. The request must have at least one of the required parameters iata, cityId or hotelId."** If i using cityid for signature and send request with this signature then the message showing invalid signature. I have contacted with support team but they giving me robotic answer.

```
http://engine.hotellook.com/api/v2/search/start.json?iata=HKT&checkIn=2016-06-10&checkOut=2016-06-13&adultsCount=2&customerIP=192.168.1.1&childrenCount=1&lang=en&currency=USD&waitForResult=0&marker=PasteYourMarkerHere&signature=e4f73624dded79bc040ebf0e5d68a3a3
```

**where signature is md5 of string:** 
    "YourToken:YourMarker:adultsCount:checkIn:checkOut:childrenCount:currency:customerIP:iata:lang:waitForResult".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first you should change **iata** code to **cityId** in your request. Second you should change and recalculate signature string, it will be look like this: "YourToken:YourMarker:adultsCount:checkIn:checkOut:childrenCount:**cityId**:currency:customerIP:lang:waitForResult". After that you can send new request with new signature.